# How do I replace a javascript object's value with a calculated value?

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting up Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking for a client who hosts their shopping cart on Shopify. I have the integration working just fine, except that Shopify's total revenue per order needs to be divided by 100 for it to be accurate. For example, an order comes in with $8.72 in revenue, but the value passed to Google Analytics is 872.

Here is the entire code for bringing Shopify's data into Google Analytics. The field I need to divide by 100 is {{ total_price }}.

```
<!-- Begin Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking -->
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{{ id }}',                             // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'myClient',                    // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '{{ total_price }}',               // Total revenue.
  'shipping': '{{ order.shipping_price }}',     // Shipping.
  'tax': '{{ order.tax_price }}'                // Tax.
  'currency': 'USD'                             // Local currency.
});

ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would the total value coming from the backend be in cents and not dollars and cents?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a different solution. Shopify provides a filter called "money_without_currency" that somehow adds a decimal in the right place, effectively dividing the amount by 100. Silly. So, I never needed to use javascript for the solution. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculation right in there, as it's standard JS:

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction',{
   // some parameters
   'revenue': {{total_price}}/100,
   // some other parameters
});
```

Comment: Just tried that, Nyuen, but didn't work.Here is how that line outputs in the web page source now:

    'revenue': 872/100,

Comment: I think that's probably because you have the {{total_price}}/100 in quotes, so it's being treated as a string. Try to remove the quotes, like what I've done in my example above.

Comment: Nyuen, I removed the quotes but it's still not working for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: By the way, you are missing a comma after {{order.tax_price}}. That would be enough to mess things up, too. Are you checking your GA Collect hits in the Network tab to see if the hits are going through at least?